# Wildcards in css for all states of a:hover, focus etc?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to apply a specific css property to any states of an element?

Eg the following is invalid:

`.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a*`

Right now I always have to repeat the css classes for each state of the `a` element, like:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: usage of this ".navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a" will apply the styles to all the states right? why mention each one, its the equivalent to wildcard

Comment: This is quite simple with LESS or SASS, is that a possibility within the project scope?

Comment: I've never used less/sass, but I'm quite free of choice. I'm only tied to `bootstrap` in conjunction with `java thymeleaf`.

Comment: welcome to css. this is how css is. deal with it or use sass, less, postcss or similar to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that,

```
.navbar .navbar-nav { a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { color:#000; } }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, you still have to provide each state(link, visisted, hover, active)

Comment: nested CSS selector is not supported, this can only be achieved in preprocessor.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Inserting this into the css file does not work. Nesting css seems not being supported.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a class for forever :**

```
a.anyState, a.anyState:hover, a.anyState:focus {
   //css code......
}
```

**After it ,insert this class to every `a` element that you want.**

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="active"><a href="#" class="Otherclasses anyState">Working</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
a.anyState, a.anyState:hover,
a.anyState:focus {
   background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)!important;
   color: inherit!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="active"><a href="#" class="anyState">I have class anyState</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#">I haven't class anyState</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Currently there isn't a solution for your problem based on using CSS only.**

But reading your statement, you are tired of repeating the same codes. Understandable, many of us do. That's why less and sass comes to the table. You can research the possibilities by Googling the syntax and some beginners tutorials or setups.

After asking the possibility to use less is a go. You can make a new function.

Less code:

```
.states(@color) {
    &:hover, &:focus, &:active { background-color: @color; color: inherit; }
}
```

Now you can reduced your repeating code to:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    // all other css code for the 'a' element.

    // this will generator all the states-code defined previously. 
    .states(@color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer no there exists nothing like a***

but

If you want override the existing bootstrap css config you have to set a more specific selector than they did.

For example

```
.foobar.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
   color: inherit;
 }
```

Or you can do it for example with !importand [Note: this is a bad practice]

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) !important;
   color: inherit !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Much as I hate using `id` selectors, it works in the case of your example. Give the link an `id` and target that instead.

```css
.red {color:red}

#link {color:green}
```

```html
<div class="red">
Hello
<a id="link" href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```